# Avoiding cyclic dependency - two tables reference each other in CREATE statement - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my postgresql assignment I have to write something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Coffee (
    name VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    body VARCHAR(10),
    referencepod INTEGER REFERENCES CoffeePod(modelnr)
);

CREATE TABLE CoffeePod(
    modelnr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    material VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    contains VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES Coffee(name),
);
```

i.e:

> Each coffee has one coffee pod that serves as “reference pod” for this
>   coffee

But only these two lines confuse me: 
`referencepod INTEGER REFERENCES CoffeePod(modelnr)` and `contains VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES Coffee(name)`

When I add those two lines to `psql` I get either `ERROR:  relation "Coffee" does not exist` or `ERROR:  relation "CoffeePod"` does not exist because of course they depend of each other.

I guess I should use `ALTER TABLE` but in my assignment they wrote a hint:

> You can implement these changes directly in the CREATE statements.

Is it even possible for two tables to reference each other in `CREATE` statement or did I misunderstood this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `alter table` to add one of the constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE Coffee (
    name VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    body VARCHAR(10),
    referencepod INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE CoffeePod(
    modelnr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    material VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    contains VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES Coffee(name),
);

ALTER TABLE Coffee ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (referencepod) REFERENCES CoffeePod(modelnr);
```